# Installing and running own VR-Game created in Unreal Engeine 4 on the PICO 4 without using a connected computer

Tags: android, unreal-engine4, packaging, virtual-reality

i am creating my own VR games in Unreal Engine 4. Now i want to play my game on the Pico 4 without using a computer so i only have to carry the Pico 4 with me. When i connect the glass to my computer the game is running perfecly how it is supposed to be. So i packaged the game in UE4 as ASTC, DXT and ETC2 and ran the installer on the glass which also worked.

But here comes the problem: When i open the app on the glass it will only show a frozen screen of the game with the gamesound but i cannot interact with the game. Does anyone know how i can solve this so the glass can be used as standalone hardware for own created games? The following screenshot shows the problem.

[Screenshot in the Pico4 showing how the app is running](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BAHil.jpg)

I really appreciate every help i can get! Thank you for reading my problem.
Greetings
Silas

I tried different packaging formats (ASTC, DXT and ETC2) and drag them onto the glass to start the installer on the glass.